# How do i replace text from a url that contains 'x' value?

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery function that replaces a text from url when an element is selected. Its working fine on the first part where if the url contains "https://data.whicdn.com/images" then replace `superthumb` to `large`.

But the second part where i want to replace '236x' to '564x' if the url contains "https://i.pinimg.com/" its not working, can you please quickly go through the following code and could you please provide me with the solution?

```js
jQuery('.img-selected').each(function() {

  var data_src = jQuery(this).data('src');
  var img_src = jQuery('.img-selected img').attr('src');
  var el_new_src = data_src.replace('superthumb', 'large');
  if (data_src.indexOf('https://data.whicdn.com/images') >= 0) {
    jQuery(this).attr('data-src', el_new_src);
  }

  var data_src = jQuery(this).data('src');
  var img_src = jQuery('.img-selected img').attr('src');
  var el_new_src = data_src.replace('236x', '564x');
  if (data_src.indexOf('https://i.pinimg.com/') >= 0) {
    jQuery(this).attr('data-src', el_new_src);
  }

  var the_srcx = data_src.split("?")[0];
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr('data-src', '');
  }, 1);
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr('data-src', the_srcx);
  }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: Provide a working snippet, where the problem is reproducible.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: What you mean `its not working` in your second part? Because if I try `var data_src = 'https://i.pinimg.com/236x'; var el_new_src = data_src.replace('236x', '564x'); console.log(el_new_src);` That work as espected;

Comment: This is actually a part of bookmarklet, i am not sure how to reproduce this in a snippet. here is the bookmarklet url though [ javascript:var%20ipinsite='My%20CMS',ipinsiteurl='https://tinyscripts.win/';(function(){if(window.ipinit!==undefined){ipinit();}else{document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='https://tinyscripts.win/wp-content/themes/ipinpro/js/test.js';}})(); ] please use this as url in your bookmark (exclude brackets '[' and ']'), give it any title. Here is a Screencast video of the error https://streamable.com/rogp0

Comment: p.s. sorry for providing insufficient info earlier (in my main post)